# Java ClassCastException

Tags: java, classcastexception

Hi I'm very new to Java and have this problem with building a DoublyLinkedList. I'm getting this error when running the test program. Can anyone advice any fix on my code? Any help is greatly appreciated!
Error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: hw3.Deque$Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E removeFirst(){                 // delete and return the item at the front
      Node temp=head;
      if (isEmpty()){ throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
      else{
          if(head.next==null){
              head=null;
              tail=null;
          }else{
                  head=head.next;
                  head.prev=null;
              }
          return (E) head;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Please [read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a **minimal, complete and verifiable** example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very suspect: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Don't suppress warnings unless you have a very good reason, and in these cases you should usually add a comment stating this reason.

If you remove this annotation you will get a compile warning on the following line:

```
return (E) head;
```

Changing this to `head.item` will fix this problem, but it's more likely that it should be:

```
return temp.item;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry can I please trouble you with another question?

Comment: @Robert it's better to just create a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("\nThe winner is %d\n", dq.removeFirst());
```

`removeFirst` returns `Node` not `Integer`.

```
public E removeFirst(){ 
  Node temp=head;
  if (isEmpty()){ throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
  else{
      if(head.next==null){
          head=null;
          tail=null;
      }else{
              head=head.next;
              head.prev=null;
          }
      return (E) head; // head is of type Node
      }
  }
```

Comment: @user2418306   any idea on a fix? Thanks